# Warning - DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Start tag expected, '<' not found in Entity

Tags: php, xml

> DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Start tag expected, '<'
>   not found in Entity

I am getting this above warning when I am running my project on Ubuntu. The xml response coming without xml tags (`<` and `>`). In windows, it is working properly.  What is the problem? How can I solve this?

Comment: Where are you getting your XML response from? Can you post any example code?

Comment: Please also show the `var_dump` of the first argument you are passing to `loadXML`

Comment: i am getting xml response from soap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means you are not passing (valid) XML to `DOMDocument::loadXML`. To fix it, pass XML to it.

Comment: But same code working in windows. I have printed xml soap response(on Ubuntu). The response did't have xml tags.

Comment: @Hearaman we got two choices here: a) you keep telling me "but" or b) you provide a reproducable test case, code snippets or the actual response. Without any of those I am unable to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is also (for some conditions like a empty root tag) a PHP BUG!

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50661

I am using "PHP Version 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6" and the bug is there.

Comment: I just ran into this on a project.  XML is perfectly legal, yet I keep getting 'start tag expected.  '<' not found'.  Thanks for posting this.