# PHP DOMXpath not scraping URL

Tags: php, xpath, web-scraping, domxpath

I am trying to get data between these tags:

```
<item><title>White Paper and Sales copy writer by stelladonsai</title>
<link>http://www.freelancer.com/projects/Technical-Writing-Academic-Writing/White-Paper-Sales-copy-writer.html</link>
<description>I need native English speaker to write a piece of white paper and a Sales copy.    *you must have experience.   *you must be native English speaker  *you must have sample to be attached with your cover... (Budget: &#36;30-&#36;250 USD, Jobs: Academic Writing, Technical Writing)</description>
<pubDate>Thu, 18 Oct 2012 17:23:10 -0400</pubDate>
<guid isPermaLink="false">Freelancer.com_project_2578329</guid>
</item>
```

The PHP code I am using is:

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHTML($txt);
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );

/*Begin Get Titles*/
$bquery = $xpath->query( "//item/title" );
$i=0;
foreach ($bquery as $b){
    $i=$i+1;
    $title[$i] = $b->nodeValue; 
}
/*End Get Titles*/

/*Begin Get Links*/
$bquery = $xpath->query( "//item/link" );
$i=0;
foreach ($bquery as $b){
    $i=$i+1;
    $link[$i] = $b->nodeValue;  
}
/*End Get Links*/
```

$txt comes from a RSS feed I scraped with CURL. The code above gets the title just fine, and any other field I want. But when I try to scrape and echo the link field I get nothing back. (I tried replacing //item/link with the other fields and they all worked).

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`loadXML`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php) instead of [`loadHTML`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) as you are loading XML not html.

http://codepad.org/0FYXiwMy

Comment: When I use that code i get this error:

    Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Start tag expected, '<' not found in Entity, line: 1 in /public_html/test/test2.php on line 31

I found this question which suggests that the RSS feed is not proper XML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736925/warning-domdocumentloadxml-domdocument-loadxml-start-tag-expected

The feed I am scraping up with CURL is here: http://www.freelancer.com/rss/job_Academic-Writing.xml

Comment: sorry i hit enter early. also sorry that comment is badly formatted. still getting used to stackoverflow. appreciate you helping me though!

Comment: @user1757890 the xml you posted is not what the feed returns?

Comment: It is what the feed returns. Each job's data is between "item" tags, i just posted 1 item tag and removed the category and coop:keyword tags because i was trying to keep my post short and i'm just trying to grab the link right now. I didn't think the rest was effecting anything. I've tried and succeeded at echoing the guid, pubDate, description, and title. link is the only thing that doesn't show up.

Comment: I just realized it is probably not working because a link tag in html is not opened and closed with data between it. for example: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">

now to figure out a way around that..

Comment: Lol really makeshift fix but it solves the problem:

$txt = str_replace("<link>", "<linkk>", $txt);
$txt = str_replace("</link>", "</linkk>", $txt);